# Newbie can't get pound reverse proxy to work- Any pointers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, reverse-proxy

I just need to set up the very simplest possible pound server on Ubuntu, but can't get any sign of life that pound works or is doing anything... probably a very simple answer to my dilemma- Any help is greatly appreciated!

First, I installed pound:

```
sudo apt-get install pound
```

Then I set startup=1 in in /etc/default/pound (because it asked me to do this to allow it to start)

For a basic test, I just want any traffic to "http://localhost:8881" when typed into my web browser on the local machine to go to google instead, so I modified /etc/pound/pound.cfg to read as follows, which I hoped would give me the result I want:

```
ListenHTTP
 Address 127.0.0.1
 Port   8881

 ## allow PUT and DELETE also (by default only GET, POST and HEAD)?:
  xHTTP     0

  Service
       BackEnd
            Address www.google.com
            Port    80
       End
  End
 End
```

Finally, I restarted pound from the console:

```
> sudo pound
starting....
```

After doing this, absolutely nothing seems to happen and control is returned to the console. If I go to http://localhost:8881 it is a dead page. When I run "ps -AL" I do not see any process named "pound". When I check "cat /var/log/messages" no message related to pound appears.

Since I'm a complete newbie there's probably a dead simple answer to my problem... Anyone know what it is? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I suggest migrating this to http://askubuntu.com/, http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks sehe- Good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this question because I found another solution and don't want people to expend energy on something I no longer need.

(My solution was to use the reverse proxy features in "tinyproxy", another linux proxy server- It worked right out of the gate and is much easier to configure as a reverse proxy, for a newbie like me at least)